# HTML to PDF in Play Framework using Itext not PDF module

Tags: java, playframework, itext

How do I render an HTML template as a PDF in the play framework using itext without using the pdf module since it is unsupported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a HTML template pretty much in the same way as in a regular Java project.
First add the dependencies to your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.itextpdf" % "itextpdf" % "5.4.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.itextpdf.tool" % "xmlworker" % "5.4.1"
```

Then, on a controller method:

```
// step 1
Document document = new Document();
// step 2
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("pdf.pdf"));
// step 3
document.open();
// step 4
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                new ByteArrayInputStream(views.html.index.render().body().getBytes()));

//step 5
document.close();

System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
```

Comment: Can you handle a dynamic scala html template the same way as you described?

Comment: Yes, replace the FileInputStream with the rendered template. Updated the code sample with a scala template.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks a lot!